# Dates of comments do not appear systematically

Tags: bug, comments

Since this morning, I realized that I can't see the date of the comments anymore. They do appear however with some comments but not systematically, and I don't really see any pattern to it.
Here's a couple of examples of what I'm talking about:

Exhibit A:

> [image]

Exhibit B:

> [image]

Exhibit C:

> [image]

I'm currently using Maxthon for Mac (version 4.1.3.4000). I, of course, cleaned up the cookies before posting this question but it didn't change anything.

Comment: let's see if can repro here...

Comment: I don't think Maxthon is supported. Can you please try with a common browser like Chrome or Firefox? The comment timestamp is being updated with JavaScript, hence browsers with weird JS can cause problems.

Comment: Indeed I can't repro this with Chrome, so it's a Maxthon issue. Any idea why it's happening since this morning but never happened before?

Comment: dunno, maybe they updated the code, changing the way JavaScript is handled.

Comment: [list of supported browsers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)